# Block access to all but a single URI with htaccess from a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to use `htaccess` to prevent access to my site unless the requests are going to a specific URI, but only when accessed from a certain subdomain.

Essentially I've a number of subdomains which I am using to get around browser request limits to speed up the loading of a page with has many images. I've tested and this is working well, preventing the browser from blocking requests until others have finished.

What I want to achieve is blocking access to the rest of the site from these subdomains, so they can only access URIs starting with `/images`. The idea being to avoid duplicate URLs for my pages or a subdomain accidentally being indexed in Google.

Try as I have, I cannot get it right, here is what I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Prevent access to anything but the /images URI from subdomains
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn[1-9]\.domain.localhost$ [NC]
    RewriteRule !^/images.* - [R=404]

</IfModule>
```

The URI I would like the subdomains to access is:

> domain.localhost/images/(products|retailers)/400/400/filename.jpg

As you may have guessed that is not a physical folder structure, its a route within my Laravel PHP application.

From my understanding the bottom rule should should be saying "If the request is from a matching domain, and the request URI does not begin with `/images` redirect to a 404 error but as it does not work I must be pretty far off the mark. I believe the issue could be due to the order of the rules but I'm unsure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Worth noting that everything beyond the bottom rules are required and used for Laravel.

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches the current server's (virtual) hostname, not the hostname of the referrer/client.

Comment: That should be fine shouldn't it? When the site is accessed via the subdomain it %{HTTP_HOST} should in fact be the subdomain? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Perhaps it's this: remove the first `/`, like so: `RewriteRule !^images.* - [R=404]`

Comment: Afraid not. I believe the issue lies with the RewriteRule. I can test to ensure that the subdomain is matching using `RewriteRule ^.* - [R=404]`. With this, all requests from the subdomain 404, but requests from the main domain are okay. My thoughts are that mod_rewrite does not see the URI as /images if other rules are processed first but just guessing

Comment: Well, it is pretty much how I do it, but I do have a `RewriteBase /` in there too. Btw, if the URIs begin with `/`, wouldn't your first rewrite rule map `/foo/` to `//foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive receives the URI on a per directory basis. So, the path it receives would not contain the leading slash (`/`). That is only accessible for rewrites done in either the server or vhost context.

I'd suggest you use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable instead for you rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn[1-9]\.domain\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```